# is this code improvable?

Tags: php

Currently my mind is under heavy pressure and I can't stay a long time focusing on one single issue, I am pretty sure that the way I made it is basic and can be improved to make it smaller and easier (more professional maybe ?) code;

```
<?php
$intro_id = rand(1,2);
if($intro_id == 1 && !empty($options['hidden_intro_one'])){
    $hidden_intro = $options['hidden_intro_one'];
}
elseif(!empty($options['hidden_intro_two'])){
    $hidden_intro = $options['hidden_intro_two'];
}
else{
    //back to circle number 1
    $hidden_intro = $options['hidden_intro_one'];
}
?>
```

**Partially SOLVED :**
the solution was to use array_rand() function like this :

```
<?php
    $random_intro = array($options['hidden_intro_one'],$options['hidden_intro_two']);
    $hidden_intro = $random_intro[array_rand($random_intro)];
?>
```

But if one of the intros is left empty, it will appear empty when you echo the code, while I want to print the other intro (if not empty) instead...

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? The code is not very self-documenting so it's hard to say how to improve it (next to saying, it should be more self-documenting).

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

It can certainly be 'improved'. Code can always be improved :) One easy improvement you can always do (more of a habit to teach yourself) is to add a comment about what the code is supposed to do.

Anyway, what (I think) you're trying to do is basically the same as:

```
$hidden_intro = $options[ array_rand( $options ) ];
```

Comment: Your making the assumption that only intros will be stored in the $options variable, the variable name implies it has more than just intro's in it.

Comment: True -- and you are making the assumption it's not :) I just rewrote the section of code I saw here, to give the guy an idea. Only he knows the requirements (and that's again exactly the reason he should add more comments to the code :) )

Comment: array_rand is what i was looking for, well your way is wrong but i used what you said to make my code better, editing the question to explain more..

Comment: but what if one of the intros is empty ? nothing will appear but i want the other intro to appear if its filled

Comment: Well, one way would be to not add it to the `$options` array. However, since we don't have any context on this code, we can't make the decision for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$intros = array(
1 => $options['hidden_intro_one'],
2 => $options['hidden_intro_two']
);

$intro_id = rand(1,2);

$hidden_intro = empty($intros[$intro_id]) ? reset($intros) : $intros[$intro_id];
?>
```

Although I don't like using reset() as a way to get the first possible value, but you can customize the 'default' value process :)

Comment: I would hardly call this an improvement... Just a different way of writing?

Comment: What if intro one and two are empty?

Comment: @Rijk if you add 10 options, this version is definitely better than the if/else. But your version rocks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
$intro        = array("hidden_intro_one","hidden_intro_two");
$hidden_intro = $options[array_rand($intro)];
```

Or, if `$options` only contains `hidden_intro_one` and `hidden_intro_two` you could just do:

```
$hidden_intro = array_rand($options);
```

**EDIT** oops, this leaves out the part where it can't be empty.

If `$options` only contains `hidden_intro_one` and `hidden_intro_two`

```
$hidden_intro = $options["hidden_intro_one"]; // fallback if both are empty

shuffle($options);

foreach($options as $option)
    if(!empty($option)){

        $hidden_intro = $option;
        break;

    }
```

Else

```
$hidden_intro = $options["hidden_intro_one"]; // fallback if both are empty

$intros = array("hidden_intro_one","hidden_intro_two");

shuffle($intros);

foreach($intros as $intro)
     if(!empty($options[$intro])){

        $hidden_intro = $options[$intro];
        break;

    }
```

This might not necessarily be better though, but it will be if you add more values.

Comment: rather use my old version than this, too much lines, all i want is simpler implementation using the array_rand if possible

Answer (score 0):

This method will allow you to use more than one intro.

```
<?php
//why not make your intro's an array in your options array
$options['hidden_intro'] = array('one', 'two');
//declare your intro variable
$hidden_intro;
//now lets loop our intro's
foreach($options['hidden_intro'] as $intro)
{
    if(!empty($intro))
    {
        $hidden_intro = $into;
        break;
    }
}

if(isset($hidden_intro))
{
    //use your intro here
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate what varies and for the standard problem use an existing function like `array_rand`:

```
$intros = get_non_empty_intros_from_options($options);

$hidden_intro = array_rand($intros);

function get_non_empty_intros_from_options($options)
{
    $intro_option_keys = array('one', 'two');
    $intro_option_key_mask = 'hidden_intro_%s';

    $intros = array();
    foreach ($intro_option_keys as $intro)
    {
        $key = sprintf($intro_option_key_mask, $intro);
        if (empty($options[$key]))
            continue
        ;
        $intros[$key] = $options[$key];
    }
    return $intros;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, an (almost) oneliner:

```
$to_be_choosen_keys = array("hidden_intro_one","hidden_intro_two");
$hidden_intro = array_rand(
    array_intersect_key(
        $options, 
        array_flip($to_be_choosen_keys)
    )
);
```